# Unknown function signature in C

Tags: c, pointers

I would be very thankful if you could explain me what the following means:

```c
void bar(char *a, char *b, unsigned short c)      // (2)
{
    ...
}

void (*foo(void))(char *, char *, unsigned short) // (1)
{
    return bar;
}
```

In particular,

- Why there are no variable names in (1)?
- What does `void (*foo(void))` mean? How can `*foo(void)` be a name?
- What does `return bar` mean? Returns it the address of the `bar` source code, or the result from `bar`, or else?
- Is there any feature in making these signatures so complicated?
- Could you give an example of the usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a *pointer to a function* that takes three arguments of types `char *`, `char *` and `unsigned short` and returns `void`.

These declarations can be quite confusing because they should be read inside-out, bouncing left and right as needed:

- `foo` is a thing ...
- `foo(void)` ... apparently a function
- `*foo(void)` ... whose return value can be dereferenced
- `(*foo(void))(...)` ... and then called with these arguments
- `void (*foo(void))(...)` ... which results in a value of type `void`.

You can also use [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) to parse complex declarations for you:

> declare foo as function (void) returning pointer to function (pointer to char, pointer to char, unsigned short) returning void

Usage examples:

```
// Immediately call the returned function.
// The similarity to the declaration is no coincidence!
(*foo())("hello", "world", 42);

// Store the returned function pointer for later invocation.
// This time there are no parentheses following the name, because
// this is a variable, not a function.
void (*fnPtr)(char *, char *, unsigned short) = foo();
(*fnPtr)("hello", "world", 42);
```

Argument names can always be omitted if the arguments aren't used inside the function. In this case, there isn't even a function body to use them in, because the body of `foo` isn't what the arguments are being passed to.

Comment: *Argument names can always be omitted if the arguments aren't used inside the function* true, but here there is no argument in a prototype... Argument names can be omitted in prototypes, whatever their usage in the definition of the function.

Comment: Yeah, they can even be different in the prototype and the definition.